# Compare MySQL Timestamp with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to compare timestamp of MySQL with current timestamp on NodeJS.

I am adding the timestamp in this way to MySQL:

```
var updateQuery = "UPDATE user SET last_pub = ? + INTERVAL 5 HOUR WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";

var mysqlTimestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
return req.dbConnection.query(updateQuery, mysqlTimestamp) // I call this to run the query
```

I compare it in this way:

```
function checkTime() {
 return req.dbConnection.query(checkUser)
   .then(([rows, fields]) => {
            if (rows != "") {
                var rowResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
                var mysqlTimestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                console.log(rowResult.last_pub)
                console.log(mysqlTimestamp)
                if (rowResult.last_pub > mysqlTimestamp) {
                    var dict = {}
                    dict.response = "wait"
                    console.log("hour not passed");
                    req.dbConnection.end()
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": dict}))
                    return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": dict}));
                }
                else {
                    console.log("done")
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error - user not exist")
            }
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

When I try to print the two timestamp I got this two:

```
2019-01-03T04:02:00.000Z (MySQL result)
2019-01-03 00:02:07 +01:00 (moment result)
```

The problem is that the hour is everytimes "hour not passed" even if the last_pub is < of mysqlTimestamp

I have done some test and when I do the check with rowResult.last_pub > mysqlTimestamp its not checking the hour but its checking the day. Because If I change the hour its always "hour not passed" but If I change the day it print "done". I have to do the check with hour too

N. = All my timestamp is in UTC (System and MySQL) and the field’s type of time where we are working is set to TIMESTAMP

Comment: When it comes to timestamps you would be better using UNIX Timestamp. Also make sure to have everything in UTC time

Comment: I got all my timestamp with UTC

Comment: Use UNIX Timestamp for any time related task

Comment: Can you give me a complete answer?

Comment: Why are you getting the current time using Node.js? Can't you get it from the database as suggested by @Pe46dro?

Comment: I have to compare it multiple times and I am doing it with code and not with query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two strings. Try replacing this :

```
            var rowResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
            var mysqlTimestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            console.log(rowResult.last_pub)
            console.log(mysqlTimestamp)
            if (rowResult.last_pub > mysqlTimestamp) {
```

with this :

```
            var rowResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
            var nodeTime = Date.now();
            var mysqlTime = new Date(rowResult.last_pub).getTime();
            if (mysqlTime > nodetime) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should generate timestamp in MySQL with the function unix_timestamp.
Then you should use MySQL perform the comparison and retrive only the lines that you need.

Functions:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/unix_timestamp/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/it/from_unixtime/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use moment functions isSameOrBefore or isSameOrAfter:

```
var moment1 = moment(rowResult.last_pub);
var moment2 = moment(); // Current datetime

moment1.isSameOrAfter(moment2);

moment1.isSameOrBefore(moment2);
```